# Find the Mistake In My Calculation For the Odds of Hitting The Fire Bet In Craps.

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

**Background Information:** Inside the game of craps, one of the most notorious bets, the fire bet, is known for  being exceptionally complicated and hard to win.  In order to hit the fire bet, every number must be made as a point.  This means that the shooter must roll a number, and then  continue to roll  until he roles that number again; however, he roles a 7 before he roles the number a second time, the bet is lost.   The goal of the shooter is to do this for the 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, and 10.

**Question:**  What are the Odds of a shooter making this Fire Bet?

**My Attempt at a solution (Wrong):** First, I will try to find the odds of rolling a four before rolling a seven.        $\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(4) * P(Anything But 4 or 7)^x$  Then, I will find the probability of rolling a 5 before a 7 and a 6 before a 7. (8, 9, 10 share the same exact probabilities  as 4, 5, and 6.)
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(4) * P(Anything But 4 or 7)^x$$
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(5) * P(Anything But 5 or 7)^x$$
$$  \sum_{x=0}^\infty P(6) * P(Anything But 6 or 7)^x$$

This is equal to 1/3, 2/5, and 5/11 respectively.

$$ \sum_{x=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{12} *  \frac{3 }{4}^x = \frac{1}{3} $$
$$   \sum_{x=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{9}  *  \frac{13}{18} ^x = \frac{2}{5} $$
$$ \sum_{x=0}^\infty  \frac{5}{36}  *  \frac{25}{36} ^x = \frac{5}{11} $$

Now, I can start putting together the final answer, which ended being incorrect.  The shooter must shoot a 4 ($\frac{1}{12}$) and then shoot the 4 again before a 7 ($\frac{1}{3}$).   The probability of making the four is $\frac{1}{12} * \frac{1}{3}$.  We can now do the same for the 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.  This leaves us with the final answer, which ended up being incorrect.

$$(\frac{1}{12} * \frac {1}{3}) * (\frac{1}{9} * \frac{2}{5}) * (\frac{5}{36} * \frac{5}{11})  * (\frac {5}{36} * \frac{5}{11})  * (\frac{1}{9} * \frac{2}{5})  * (\frac{1}{12} * \frac{1}{3}) $$

This gives us the final answer of $\frac{5}{8019}$ ; however, this answer is completely wrong. Can someone help me spot my mistake?

(Please note that the first set of computations that yield the answer $\frac{1}{3}$ , $\frac{2}{5}$ , and $\frac{5}{11}$ are correct, but the final answer is not correct.  Thank You.)

The answer I got isn't correct.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but the six-way fire bet I've read about requires the player to roll all five other numbers before rolling out on point (and before rolling a $7$, of course). They don't have to be rolled in order, which may be a fact you're not accounting for. ¶ By the way, please be a bit more judicious about how you choose the topic tags. There's nothing in here fundamentally about calculus or infinity, so I'll remove those tags. You're free to add them back in if you think I've taken them out in error, but again, please be judicious, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for fixing up my post! I will try to explain some of the confusion about what I was trying to do. I have accounted for the fact that they do not have to be in order in be final computation. The correct answer seems to be way smaller than my answer. Something appears to be missing.

Comment: I don't think you've got the fire bet right. What it seems to be is that you roll any of $4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10$. You must then keep rolling until you reroll the point, without rolling a $7$ first. Even after that, however, you only win the fire bet if in addition, you've rolled all five other numbers first. Therefore, the sequence $6, 4, 9, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 4, 6$ wins the fire bet, while the sequence $5, 4, 10, 4, 6, 8, 5$ fails, as does (of course) $8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 7$. ¶ To be honest, this seems tedious to compute. Maybe there's some short cut I'm missing. What is the answer?

Comment: (Of course, any number of $2, 3, 11, 12$ can appear arbitrarily often in the interior of the sequence.)

Comment: A fire bet only relies on the amount of points that are made. If a five is rolled back to back, it counts a one of the points for the fire bet. This even has a name. It is called a buck shot.

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were asking for the one specifically where you get all six points?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a long calculation.

Let's look at the probability just for making the points $4,5,6,8,9,10$ in that order without ever have a seven-out on a point:

- Probability the first point value is $4$ is $\frac{3}{24}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{3}{9}$
- Probability then rolling new point value before seven-out is $\frac{\frac{21}{24}}{1-\frac{3}{24}\frac{3}{9}}$
- Probability then new point value is $5$ is $\frac{4}{21}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{4}{10}$
- Probability then rolling new point value before seven-out is $\frac{\frac{17}{24}}{1-\frac{3}{24}\frac{3}{9}-\frac{4}{24}\frac{4}{10}}$
- Probability then new point value is $6$ is $\frac{5}{17}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{5}{11}$
- Probability then rolling new point value before seven-out is $\frac{\frac{12}{24}}{1-\frac{3}{24}\frac{3}{9}-\frac{4}{24}\frac{4}{10}-\frac{5}{24}\frac{5}{11}}$
- Probability then new point value is $8$ is $\frac{5}{12}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{5}{11}$
- Probability then rolling new point value before seven-out is $\frac{\frac{7}{24}}{1-\frac{3}{24}\frac{3}{9}-\frac{4}{24}\frac{4}{10}-\frac{5}{24}\frac{5}{11}-\frac{5}{24}\frac{5}{11}}$
- Probability then new point value is $9$ is $\frac{4}{7}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{4}{10}$
- Probability then rolling new point value before seven-out is
  $\frac{\frac{3}{24}}{1-\frac{3}{24}\frac{3}{9}-\frac{4}{24}\frac{4}{10}-\frac{5}{24}\frac{5}{11}-\frac{5}{24}\frac{5}{11}-\frac{4}{24}\frac{4}{10}}$
- Probability then new point value is $10$ is $\frac{3}{3}$
- Probability of then making that point is $\frac{3}{9}$

You multiply all those together and get a very small number. Then you do the same for the other $6!-1$ permutations.  Then add them all up.

Here is some R code that does that:

```
possiblepoints <- c(4:6, 8:10)
numpoints <- length(possiblepoints)
numperms <- factorial(numpoints)
ways <- 6 - abs(7 - (1:12)) 

permutations <- function(n){
    ## from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199902/672221
    ## by user Museful 
    if(n==1){
        return(matrix(1))
    } else {
        sp <- permutations(n-1)
        p <- nrow(sp)
        A <- matrix(nrow=n*p,ncol=n)
        for(i in 1:n){
            A[(i-1)*p+1:p,] <- cbind(i,sp+(sp>=i))
        }
        return(A)
    }
}

pointperms<- matrix(possiblepoints[permutations(numpoints)],ncol=numpoints)

probabilities <- rep(1, numperms)
notcomeout <- 6^2 - ways[2] - ways[3] - ways[12] - ways[7] - ways[11]
remainways <- rep(notcomeout, numperms)
newdenom <- rep(1, numperms)
```

then going through the six points

```
for (k in 1:numpoints){
  probnewpointbeforesevenout <- remainways / notcomeout / newdenom 
  probabilities <- probabilities * probnewpointbeforesevenout 
  probthisnewpoint <- ways[pointperms[,k]] / remainways 
  probabilities <- probabilities * probthisnewpoint 
  probmakingpoint <- ways[pointperms[,k]] / (ways[pointperms[,k]]+ways[7])
  probabilities <- probabilities * probmakingpoint
  remainways <- remainways - ways[pointperms[,k]] 
  newdenom <- newdenom - probmakingpoint*ways[pointperms[,k]]/notcomeout   
}

sum(probabilities)
# 0.0001624347
1/sum(probabilities)
# 6156.318
```

and those final figures seem to be the same as values published by Mark Bollman and [Michael Shackleford](https://wizardofodds.com/games/craps/side-bets/fire-bet/)

Comment: Why is the probability of roling each number out of 24 instead of 36?

Comment: @Kyotiq - because a comeout roll of 2, 3, 7, 11, or 12 is ignored, and they have probability $\frac{1+2+6+2+1}{36}=\frac{12}{36}$ with $24=36-12$

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses exponential generating functions to show that the probability of winning the fire bet is $0.000162435$.

Let $p_n$ be the probability of rolling $n$ with a pair of dice:
$$\begin{matrix}
n &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12\\
p_n &1/36 &2/36 &3/36 &4/36 &5/36 &6/36 &5/36 &4/36 &3/36 &2/36  &1/36\\
\end{matrix}$$
If the point (the first roll in a game) is $n$, then the probability of rolling the point before rolling a $7$ is
$$\frac{p_n}{p_n + p_7}$$
The rules require that the point is one of $\{4,5,6,8,9,10\}$. Consequently, the probability of rolling a point of $n$ and also winning the game is
$$s_n =\frac{p_n^2}{p_n + p_7}$$

As a first step, we would like to find the probability of winning the fire bet when the last point made is $4$, so we have a sequence of games in which the player never "sevens out", all of the points $5,6,8,9$ and $10$ are rolled with success at least once, and the final point of $4$ (which is won) is the first occurrence of $4$ as a point.  Any number of initial "points" of $2,3,7,11$ or $12$ may appear in the sequence of points; these have no effect on the fire bet. Let $a_n$ be the probability of a sequence of $n$ games in which all the points $5,6,8,9$ and $10$ are rolled with success at least once and $4$ is never a point--in other words, a sequence of games suitable to win the fire bet with final point of $4$ up to just before rolling $4$ as a point.  The exponential generating function of $a_n$ is
$$f_4(x) = e^{(p_2+p_3+s_7+p_{11}+p_{12})x} \prod_{n \in \{5,6,8,9,10\}} (e^{s_n x}-1)$$

The probabiity of winning the fire bet when the last point made is $4$ is then
$$w_4 = s_4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = s_4 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f_4(x) \; dx = 0.0000299565 \tag{*}$$
(I used Mathematica to evaluate the integral, a task which would otherwise be tedious and error-prone.)

Proceeding analogously for the cases in which the final points in a winning sequence are $5$ or $6$, we find $w_5=0.0000270913 $ and $w_6=0.0000241696$.  By symmetry $w_4=w_{10}$, $w_5=w_9$, and $w_6=w_8$, s0 the probability of winning the fire bet is
$$2(w_4+w_5+w_6) = \boxed{0.000162435}$$

$(*)$ Note: If $$f_4(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{1}{n!}x^n$$ then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f_4(x) \; dx$$
provided the integral converges, because of the identity $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^n \; dx = n!$.